# show what command is used in graphical mode

Tags: 14.04, bash, debugging, bash-history

Is it possible to use some kind of verbose to show on the terminal what commands are executed when using graphical mode? For example: if I click on chrome it must show: google-chrome. 
My goal is to use it on configuration to know what's being executed when I change some parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you run the command from the terminal and watch the terminal to see the changes, if I got you right

Comment: then what's the comand for enter into graphical configuration in gnome ?

Comment: Try `gnome-control-center`

Comment: doesn't help. Not showing the command executed

Comment: You are confused. Not all GUI programs resolve to commands.

Comment: at the back aren't they executed programs?